# JWT tymon/jwt-auth refresh token in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth, jwt

I am using tymon/jwt-auth library in Laravel to generate token. At the moment I am able to create the token:

```
$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)
```

The point is I need to generate also a refresh token to return to the user, how can I do it? The final results should be like this:

```
{
"jwt":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi . . .",
"refresh_token":  "b5ed616d32 . . ."
}
```

Comment: Hi Stefano, I'm looking for same think, do you have foun a solution?